# courier-imap disabled IDLE still working

Tags: courier

Due to short check interval of email clients and many imapd processes, i removed IDLE from IMAP_CAPABILITY in /etc/courier/imapd config

```
 IMAP_CAPABILITY="IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA"
 IMAP_IDLE_TIMEOUT=0
 IMAP_ENHANCEDIDLE=0
```

After restart, i checked it using telnet. Idle is not listed in capabilities after login, but is still enabled and i can use it.

How can i really disable IDLE?

Comment: I think the only way is to modify the source code.  The developer says it is [always enabled](https://www.mail-archive.com/courier-imap%40lists.sourceforge.net/msg03541.html).  On a side note, removing IDLE will not improve the situation with email clients checking mail too often, it will actually make it worse.